# Should I use stencil for this?

Tags: texturing

I'm not quite sure how I should do those 3 blue speckles on my character's head.

First I thought creating some kind of black and white stencil and paint over it, but  I'm afraid that would leave the edges of the blue circles jagged(?)

How would you guys texture the head?

I'm using Cycles.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may create a ***procedural b&w mask*** and use it as a factor for mixing different shaders. It requires some experimenting to do it right but give you the full control over the dots' shape and sharpness. You may also create a b&w mask via ***Texture Paint*** mode.
[image]

- #### PROCEDURAL MASK

  Set up the material nodes as pictured below. Set up the texture coordinates to *Object* and play with the *Mapping* node settings to place the dot where you want. Set the *Gradient Texture*'s mode to *Quadratic Sphere*. Use *Color Ramp* node to set its blurriness.
  [image]

  Now duplicate the nodes with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and mix them using *MixRGB* color node (*Multiply*). 
  [image]

  Play with the settings of the duplicated *Mapping* node to place the dot on the top part/other side of the object.
  [image]

  By repeating the process you'll get a b&w mask for mixing the two shaders.
  [image]
- #### PAINTED MASK

  Unwrap the sphere (I marked a seam along the vertical edge loop and then unwrapped). Go to ***Texture Paint*** mode and add a new *Diffuse Color* paint slot. Set the image color to pure white. In painting tools set the brush color to black and set the curve's type to *line* e.g. In *Options* bookmark uncheck the *Occlude*, *Cull* and *Normal* checkboxes to paint through the mesh. Paint the dots and save your image. Use it as a mask as in the *procedural* example above.
  [image]

Here's the .blend: [image]

Answer (score 2):

### Final:

You can do it with procedural material. It will give you full control over circle placement and size.

[image: Final]

### Overview and Node Setup:

Material is really simple, tricky part is circle placement.

1. This method will work with **Texture Coordinates > Object**. If you want to use **Generated** or **UV Map**, then values in mapping nodes will change.
2. In **Mapping Nodes** *Location X* value should always be the same as in *Scale X, Y, Z* but positive. Loc: 2, Scale: 2, 2, 2. Loc: -2, Scale: 2, 2, 2.
3. Middle Circle is on the other side of the Sphere so it's height is controlled differently then others. By X axis.
4. **ColorRamp > Constant** will give you hard edges. If you want to smooth them change to **Ease** or something else. Also **White value** control Circle size.

[image: Node]

### Blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Add three/four circles and align them with the headwear.
2. Use Knife Project and assign a new material to the circles that appear on the headwear.
3. Delete the circles you added when you're done.